# How to read content description of any android app's view/layout using uiautpmator2 in python

Tags: python, ui-automation

I am using uiautomator2 and python to write ui automation for android app. How to read content description of any android app's view/layout using uiautpmator2 in python?

I have tried below code and I am not sure how to read content description

```
import uiautomator2 as u2
import subprocess 
adb_device = subprocess.run('adb devices', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

amc = u2.connect(adb_device.stdout.split('\n')[1][:-7]) 

amc(text="",resourceId="com.company.le.mesh.meshapp:id/toolbar_layout",className="android.widget.FrameLayout",contentDesc='New Room').exists()
```

I am not able to read content description of android app layout/view. Instead getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "C:\Users\jhaavinash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\uiautomator2\__init__.py", line 1312, in __call__
    return UiObject(self, Selector(**kwargs))   File "C:\Users\jhaavinash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\uiautomator2\_selector.py", line 52, in __init__
    self[k] = kwargs[k]   File "C:\Users\jhaavinash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\uiautomator2\_selector.py", line 73, in __setitem__
    raise ReferenceError("%s is not allowed." % k) ReferenceError: contentDesc is not allowed.
```

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Also please do check the [help centre's article on formatting](/help/formatting). That shows you how to format code. I've edited quite a few of your answers, as you used excessive super huge bold title style formatting. I assume those came from using line-separators. Please make sure you don't burn people's eyes with abusive formatting by checking the preview before posting your question or answer.

Answer (score 0):

the info keyword of uiautomator 2 helped here.
Below code helped me in reading content-desc of layout.

```
amc(resourceId='com.cypress.le.mesh.meshapp:id/toolbar_layout').info['contentDescription']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
print(amc.xpath("//[@content-desc='new room']").exists)
```

To get all values from content-desc in classes "ViewGroup" and "TextView":

```
for el in amc.xpath("//android.widget.TextView").all():
    print("content-desc:", el.info['contentDescription'])

for el in amc.xpath("//android.view.ViewGroup").all():
    print("content-desc:", el.info['contentDescription'])
```

[Github source](https://github.com/openatx/uiautomator2)